# Calling functions with different number of parameters

Tags: c++

I have multiple functions with different numbers of parameters, e.g.

```
double foo(double x, double y) { return x + y; }

double bar(double x, double y, double z) { return x + y + z; }

double zoo(double x, double y) { return x * y; }
```

I'd like to call the functions by their names using some catchall function in the following manner:

```
call_function("foo", x, y);
call_function("bar", x, y, z);
```

It can be assumed that both parameters and function return have the same type (e.g. `double` as in the above example). Unfortunately due to complex nature of the project I cannot change the functions I call and I need to deal with them as-is.

Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: And the first parameter has to be a string like that?

Comment: You can just give them the same name or write wrapper functions for each of them and give the wrapper functions the same name. The compiler will call the right one based on the number of parameters you specify.

Comment: @Martin this would be preferable since it would be easiest for me just to be able to say "call the foo function" without bothering about anything else.

Comment: @Galik you're right, but I have multiple functions with same number of parameters, so it won't work for me. I'll edit to make it more precise.

Comment: Is the first parameter for `call_function` known at compilation time?

Comment: `std::any` and a `map<std::string, std::function>`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, the first parameter is known, the types of all the other parameters and the output are known and the same for all functions, so there is no "unexpected" things to happen (at least in the example ;) ), it's just about the wrapper function.

Comment: Then I am not sure how calling them with a string parameter differs from giving them unique names? Can you explain more about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Galik this is what I do right now, but the problem is that each of those functions is called with lots of code I need to copy and paste before and after calling the functions, so instead of repeating myself I'd like to use a single function that does the other things and calls one of the functions. This is important as the project expands and for maintenance of the code.

Comment: If the code before and after the functions is the same, you should wrap it into two separate functions, and then put them into separate wrappers for each function you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define CALL(fn, x, y) fn(x, y)
#define CALL(fn, x, y, z) fn(x, y, z)
```

allows you to do:

```
CALL(foo, 13, 6);
CALL(bar, 1, 2, 3);
```

Would that be good enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called `overloading`, that is the ability to declare the same method (same name) but with different number of parameters.

Comment: What you describe is called over loading, and not what the question is about i believe

Comment: You are right, but it seemed to me that the intention of the OP was to do something like this. I might be wrong though.